# Google chrome become unresponsive on my JS code?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

I used google chrome console to test my js functions. for a particular problem i was writing code in there. the code was following

```
function isPrime(num){
    x=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
    while(x>1){
        if(num%x==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

if i called the function like `is_Prime(100)` instantly resulted false. but afterward it stopped replying anything. the page where i turned on become unresponsive. If there is a serious problem with my code why does it results in the first time. can anyone please tell me why this should happen? Thanks in advances.

Comment: There's nothing in the loop changing the value of `x` or `num`, so the loop will stop executing at the first round or never...

Comment: Please show us the calling code -- as Teemu sezs, this code has an endless loop.

Comment: You really need to step through this and think about what every step really does, not what you want it to do.

Comment: @Teemu it seems that you are the first who answered my problem first. But how can i accept you as it's now a comment. and if i accept the same solution people gave later, its not ethical. What should i do?

Comment: Me? No, lelloman beated me by six seconds : ), just accept his answer.

Comment: as requested ;) anyway thanks everyone who helped me finding out the stupidest mistake. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not changing x value, looks like an infinite loop.